# Calling the DirectMethod by passing the String Values as parameters in ConfirmMessage Box Handler

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I am trying to pass the string values to Direct Method by using the following code.

```
<html>
 <head runat="server"> 
    <script runat="server">
       protected void btnSubmit_DirectClick(object sender, Ext.Net.DirectEventArgs e)
            {
               string Name = "Lewis Bland";
               string Address = "Las Angels";
          X.Msg.Confirm("Confirmation", "Do you want to submit the Details", new MessageBoxButtonsConfig
           {
            Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
                {
                Handler = "#{DirectMethods}.fnSaveNameAndAdress(" + Name + "," + Address + ")",
                Text = "Yes"
                },
               No = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
                  {
                  Text = "No"
                    }
            }).Show(); 
     }

  [DirectMethod(Namespace = "TestAlias")] 
  public void fnSaveNameAndAdress(string Name, string Address)
   {
        X.Msg.Alert("Conformed", "Name and Address Submitted Successfully").Show();
   } 
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" ID="resource" SourceFormatting="true" />
     <ext:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnDirectClick="btnSubmit_DirectClick" />
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

> The above code working fine with out any parameters but when i pass
>   string parameters it didn't fire the Method.   To fire this method i
>   have used "Alias" Concept by reading the posts by adding the following
>   lines

```
 [DirectMethod(Namespace = "TestAlias")]
```

> and In CodeBehind i have added the the following line above the
>   Class.

```
[DirectMethodProxyID(IDMode = DirectMethodProxyIDMode.Alias, Alias = "TestAlias")]
```

> Even though i added these, it does fired any Event.   How to overcome
>   this scenario.
>
> Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
                {
                Handler = "#{DirectMethods}.fnSaveNameAndAdress(" + Name + "," + Address + ")",
                Text = "Yes"
```

inside your code handler should be like this I guess,

```
Handler = "TestAlias.fnSaveNameAndAdress(" + Name + "," + Address + ")",
```